# Can we change gradle plugin version in Android studio 3.2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android studio is the latest version android plugin version 3.2.1 . can i change it ?

Comment: Yes, but you might have to change the version of Gradle too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, But for it to work, ensure you have disabled offline mode for the android studio to download the version that you have changed to. If you face errors during gradle sync, the problem might be either the version you are fetching is not available or offline mode is enabled. To disable offline mode, Go to `File>Settings>Build>Gradle` and uncheck the offline button

[image]